# Why does the same code works differently?

Tags: python, time, sleep

Well, I have read that stdout is line-buffered. But the code works differently in Pydroid 3(unaware of the exact version) and Python 3.8.3.

```
import time
print('Hello', end = '')
time.sleep(5)
print('World')
```

In Pydroid 3, both Hello and World are printed after (at least after) 5 seconds while in Python 3.8.3, Hello is printed first, and World is printed after 5 seconds.

Why is the code working differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably not a Python version issue, but a different terminal issue.

Some terminals (or more accurately files/streams, `stdout` included) only flush after a newline (which the first `print` doesn't have), while others can flush after every write.

to force a flush you can use [`flush=True` as a param to print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), try this:

```py
import time
print('Hello', end='', flush=True)
time.sleep(5)
print('World')
```

Comment: Oh!! So stdout is line-buffered in one case while unbuffered in the another, right?

Comment: @NSR yes, seems to me that this is the case. If I run your original code from PyCharm or directly from Windows' cmd, I get different results as well (same Python version...)